# Contact form not working while click on submit button

Tags: php, html, form-submit, contact-form, submit-button

I was working with an HTML contact form, its action is a mail sending php script. But it is not working when i am clicking on the send button. I couldn't find any possible here. Please someone help me to fix this.

**HTML form**

```
<div class="contact-form">
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post">
<div class="control-group"><label class="nameLabel" for="name">Name</label> <input id="name" name="name" type="text" /></div>

<div class="control-group"><label class="emailLabel" for="email">Email</label> <input id="email" name="email" type="text" /></div>

<div class="control-group"><label class="messageLabel" for="message">Message</label><textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea></div>

<div class="control-group"><button type="submit">Send</button></div>
</form>

<h1 class="status-message-contact"></h1>
</div>
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $query = $_POST['message'];
    $email_from = $name.'<'.$email.'>';

 $to="sarath.sarigama@gmail.com";
 $subject="WEB Enquiry!";
 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: ".$email_from."\r\n";
 $message="   

         Name:
         $name     
         <br>
         Email-Id:
         $email        
         <br>
         Message:
         $query        

   ";
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
        header("Location:../index.php?msg=Successful Submission! Thankyou for contacting us.");
    else
        header("Location:../index.php?msg=Error To send Email !");
        //contact:-your-email@your-domain.com
 }
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you press the send button? Does the page load? Or does it redirect you to ../index.php?msg=Error To send Email !

Comment: nothing happens when i click on that submit button

Answer (score 2):

you dont have **submit** button name ,change **name** of the button

```
<button name='submit' type="submit">Send</button>
```

or use `input` tag

```
<input name='submit' type='submit'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<button type="submit">Send</button>
```

with

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
```

And maybe add

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1" />
```

For the isset( $_POST['submit'] )

Comment: Are you being redirected to the form action URL or is the form not submitting?

Comment: in jsFiddle how do we use php

Comment: Don't think we can yet. However since we can't reach the PHP yet either, it may help me (or someone) find a solution.